# Каким образом можно не выполнять заново код?

Tags: python

Есть код, который мы пишем в среде разработки. По ходу его формирования, на каждом этапе мы его "проверяем". На выполнение сложных программ у нас уходит много времени, потому что выполнение файла происходит с самого начала.

Если мы рассматриваем обработку данных, следует на определенном этапе сохранять изменения в новый файл и уже после этого начинать работать с ним?

Comment: Не понял, что значит *на каждом этапе мы его "проверяем"*. Кто мы? Что значит "проверяем"?

Comment: Ни че го не понял... (

Comment: Я так понимаю, что речь идет о системе контроля версий типа `Git`. Но это чисто  домыслы, из вопроса не понятно, что автор в результате хочет

Comment: @dlm0n , кто мы? Мы это значит я, либо тот у кого возник такой же вопрос. Проверяем - значит, когда ты пишешь код, то ты его запускаешь на некоторых этапах. Или ваш код в сотни строк без ошибок и проверок пишется на раз два?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

модульностью. пишешь часть логики в одном модуле. который формирует результат. потом пишешь второй, который используя результат первого выполняет еще работу. pickle, поможет тебе сохранять состояние объектов.

что еще? готовые заранее наборы данных разложить по файлам, каждую работу разбить на методы. написать тесты (unittest) под каждый метод, кадждому методу передать часть данных необходимую для тестирования. как мне кажется самый хороший вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться `ipython` либо в "чистом" виде, либо в виде `Jupyter Notebook`, что ещё удобнее. В `Jupyter Notebook` можно выполнять отдельные "ячейки" с кодом, причём в произвольном порядке. Состояние переменных при этом сохраняется в памяти. Можно пробовать запускать разные куски кода, не запуская при этом весь код "с нуля". Дописать на ходу код и запустить его с текущим состоянием памяти и переменных. Для исследовательских целей и чтобы разобраться как что-то работает, попробовать всякое, это очень удобно. Посмотреть и попробовать, как это выглядит, можно, например, в [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/).

Comment: Про Юпитер думал, но в нем не очень удобно работать. Спасибо за идею!

Comment: кажется PyCharm это умеет

Comment: @alex в нем и работаю

Comment: ну так ставишь брик поинт и после остановки переходишь на вкладку консоль в окне отладчика, где можно активировать (или включить автоматическую активацию в параметрах запуска) пайтон промпт и писать код прям на лету. после чего можно продолжить выполнение. так же запуск до курсора есть и возможность отправить в пайтон консоль любой выделеный участок кода. не знаю инструмента лучше)